# Is there a way to modify a value when its changed after rendering without useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-i18next

I have a react app that fetches the data that I need on render.
When the data arrives, I have a `useEffect` in place that will format the data and update the variable required.

My issue now is that the format function that we are using has been changed to a hook, which I can't use in the useEffect anymore, and I was wondering if there was a way to basically replicate the process without the `useEffect`

For a simplified example, originally I had something similar to this component:

```
const MyComponent = ({myValue}) => {
    const [outputVal, setOutputVal] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (myValue != null) setOutputVal(formatCurrency(myValue));
    }, [myValue]);

[...]
```

`formatCurrency` was a simple function using the `Intl.NumberFormat` functionality, and would just convert the value as needed. I've now swapped to using the `react-i18next` library, which has other functionality that I want, but it uses hooks, which means I can't use the function within the `useEffect`.

I've tried to change it to use the function when the page loads, ie:

```
const [outputVal, setOutputVal] = useState(formatCurrency(myValue));
```

The issue that I've found though is that the initial value of `myValue` is null, and the function doesn't rerun when `myValue` is updated.

Any help or info on this would be great.

Comment: No you can't, you must have another useEffect.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run `formatCurrency(myValue)` on every render and just treat it like an ordinary variable? i.e. `const outputVal = formatCurrency(myValue); return ( <p>{outputVal}</p> );`

Comment: @cbr you are amazing... I can't believe I didn't try something so simple, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `formatCurrency` probably just formats the numerical value into a string, you could just run it on every render and treat it like any ordinary variable you'd use during rendering, i.e.:

```
const MyComponent = ({myValue}) => {
    const outputVal = formatCurrency(myValue);
    return <p>{outputVal}</p>
};
```